# Stream Analytics - Reference Data

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have to set a pipe line to get data's into "stream analytics job service" from sql database directedly( should not use other layers/components Ex: Data factory, Event hubs etc between sql db and stream analytics job ) . But no stream input in my use case. Tried by using this link with by adding reference data input option

"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-reference-data "

But received "Query must refer to at least one data stream input" this error. Query expects always at least one stream input.

Please let me know to to achieve this with out using code only through pipelines.

Thank You.

Comment: Yes you can create a SQL Reference source in stream analytics but this makes no sense without a stream that would use the reference. What stream do you want to use? So far your problem doesn't make sense - can you clarify?

Comment: Also statements like _should not use other layers/components Ex: Data factory, Event hubs etc between sql db and stream analytics job_ should be backed up with some kind of reasoning. You can certainly add _reference_ data like this but you can't add streaming data without a streaming source and the intermediary is usually event hubs.

Comment: Thank you. We have to pull live sql  db data's. its historical data's to analyses and we don't preferer to another component's ( like event hub ) to avoid cost & maintance.        "SQL DB -> Stream Analysticts Jobs -> Send to Event hub" have to set this flow

Comment: As per the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs you can only stream four types of sources and none are SQL Server. To stream SQL server you need an agent that decides what to stream (the whole table? recent changes to the table) the you push that into event hubs. I agree with keeping the solution simple, but you have a complex problem, and stream analytics does not support what you want

Comment: Thank you. What the other best option to pull sql servr table data's and process on records after that send to other components such as event hub etc

Comment: The normal data flow is SQL Server > Some kind of streaming agent > Event Hub > Stream Analytics > other stuff . I don't know why you insist on having event hub only as a sink to Stream Analytics but disallow it  as a source. I suggest you carefully read the MS documentation on Stream Analytics and Event Hub so you can understand how these things fit together.

Comment: For example note that blob storage can be a source for stream analytics. So you could create an agent that writes SQL data to blob storage and stream analytics picks it up from there. But it is likely that using even hubs would be easier, depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

To set up a process where you must stream data directly from SQL to Azure Stream Analysis is directly not available. As SQL is only used as reference input not as a stream input and there only below three Stream inputs which you can opt:

- Azure Event Hubs
- Azure IoT Hub
- Azure Blob storage
- Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2

And could use as SQL as a reference input i.e. A reference data set / Lookup Table is a finite data collection that is either static or slowly changing in nature, and it is used to execute a search or to supplement your data streams.

Hence, in this scenario the only way out is to Stream SQL data using Apache Kafka and then integrating with Azure Event Hubs which could then directly be a Steam input for Azure Stream Analytics.

[Stream data as input into Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs)

[Use Azure Event Hubs from Apache Kafka applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview)